# Sql retrieve data in blocks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I stuck at the sql data retrieve. I have database which contain the data in chunks or groups like 10 records of one type then 10 records of other type and then again first type records.

like below table

```
id  time   group
=================
1   12:30  xyz
2   12:40  xyz
3   12:50  null
4   1:00   null
5   1:10   abc
6   1:20   abc
7   1:30   xyz
8   1:40   xyz
```

so in above example I have three groups like xyz,null,abc. I need time spend on xyz, null and abc individual.

I want

```
id  time  group
==================
1   20    xyz              
2   30    null
3   20    abc
```

I hope it make sense, like total time spend is 70.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to look at grouping ([`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)). The problem with your question is that you're expecting us to do the work for you.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Things like this are actually kind of tricky in SQL. Can't you process this in your application for example? If not, have a look at `row_number` and CTEs.

Comment: how the time is calculated?

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated.  You need to identify the groups.  You have two ways of doing this.  One way is to use `lead()`.  Another is to identify the groups and use that information for grouping.  Here is the second method, using a difference of row numbers to get the groups.

This gets the information for each grouping of records:

```
select group, min(time) as firsttime, max(time) as lasttime
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) -
              row_number() over (order by id, group)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by group, grp;
```

What you ultimately want is another level of aggregation:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(id)), group,
       sum(datediff(minute, firsttime, lasttime)) as time
from (select group, min(time) as firsttime, max(time) as lasttime,
             min(id) as id
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (order by id) -
                    row_number() over (order by id, group)
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
      group by group, grp
     ) t
group by group;
```

Note:  `group` is a lousy name for a column because it is a SQL reserved word.  I assume the real names are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can join this table to itself to join each record to a next one within the same group. This will allow you to calculate time spent:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(t1.id) as id, SUM(t2.time - t1.time) as time, group
FROM myTable t1 LEFT JOIN 
     myTable t2 ON t1.group = t2.group and t2.id = t1.id + 1
GROUP BY group
```

Here assumption is that your ID field does not have gaps.

If ID field has gaps, you will need to change the query to this:

```
 SELECT 
     MIN(t1.id) AS id, SUM(t2.time - t1.time) as time, group
    FROM myTable t1 LEFT JOIN 
         myTable t2 ON t1.group = t2.group AND t1.id < t2.id
         NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT * FROM myTable 
             WHERE id > t1.id and id < t2.id)
 GROUP BY group
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #myTable;

SELECT 
    id, time, grp
INTO 
    #myTable
FROM 
    (VALUES
    (1, CAST('12:30' AS time), 'xyz'),
    (2, '12:40', 'xyz'),
    (3, '12:50', NULL),
    (4, '13:00', NULL),
    (5, '13:10', 'abc'),
    (6, '13:20', 'abc'),
    (7, '13:30', 'xyz'),
    (8, '13:40', 'xyz')
    ) dt(id, time, grp)

SELECT 
    MIN(t1.id) as id, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.time, t2.time)) as time, 
    t1.grp
FROM 
    #myTable t1 LEFT JOIN 
    #myTable t2 ON ISNULL(t1.grp, 1) = ISNULL(t2.grp, 1) and t2.id = t1.id + 1
GROUP BY 
    t1.grp
ORDER BY 
    1
```